# JSF Pass parameter to another page

Tags: jsf

In JSF how do you pass a parameter from one page to another without using managed beans?

e.g.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myObjects}" var="object">
<h:column>              
        <h:commandButton value="View Object" action="view-object"/>
</h:column>                                             
</h:dataTable>
```

I want to pass the object so an the next page I can simply do #{object.displayValue}

Thxs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you can't do this without using a managed bean.

The best approach would be using a [`DataModel`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html) as the `value` of the `h:dataTable` so that you can retrieve the currently selected row object by [`DataModel#getRowData()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html#getRowData%28%29). You only need to ensure that the bean preserves the same model in the subsequent request. In other words, fill the model in the constructor of the bean.

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{bean.model}" var="item">
        <h:column>              
            <h:commandButton value="View Object" action="#{bean.view}"/>
        </h:column>                                             
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

With a request (or session) scoped bean which look like this:

```
public class Bean {

    private DataModel model;
    private Item item;

    public Bean() {
        List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
        list.add(new Item(1, "value1"));
        list.add(new Item(2, "value2"));
        list.add(new Item(3, "value3"));
        model = new ListDataModel(list);
    }

    public String view() {
        item = (Item) model.getRowData();
        return "view";
    }

    public DataModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

}
```

I assume that you're using JSF 1.x and not 2.x yet, else a `@ViewScoped` bean was [better](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html).

And in the next page:

```
<p>#{bean.item.value}</p>
```

Comment: I set up my dataTable this way, using JSF2.0, glassfish 3.0.1, and a ViewScoped bean. When I navigate to my display page, nothing shows. It seems that when I navigate away from the page with the dataTable all the variables go out of scope.