# How can i pass param from one page forward other page?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

In my page1.xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{page_one.name}" />
    <h:commandButton action="#{page_one.onSubmit}" value="Submit" />
</h:form>
```

PageOneBean.class

```
@ManagedBean(name="page_one")
@RequestScoped
public class PageOneBean {
    private String name;
    public String onSubmit(){
    return "/page2.xhtml";
    }
}
```

page2.xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton action="#{page_two.onSubmit}" value="Submit" />
</h:form>
```

PageTwoBean.class

```
@ManagedBean(name = "page_two")
@RequestScoped
public class PageTwoBean {
private String name;
public String onSubmit() {
    System.out.println("name" + name);
    return null;
}
}
```

how can i get pageOneBean.name in pageTwoBean when i click page_two.onSubmit button?

Comment: you need to use another scope on PageOneBean or pass the param via the url, have a look at this: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html

Comment: check it here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010732/jsf-pass-parameter-to-another-page

Answer (score 3):

Page2.xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <f:metadata>
         <f:viewParam name="name" value="#{page_two.name}"/>            
    </f:metadata>

    <h:commandButton action="#{page_two.onSubmit}" value="Submit" />
</h:form>
```

Bean1:

```
public class PageOneBean {
private String name;
public String onSubmit(){
    return "/page2.xhtml?name=something";
}
public void setName(String name){ this.name = name;}
public String getName(){ return name; }
}
```

Try that and see how it goes.